# pandas, combine rows based on certain column values and NAN

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
id_1    id_2    value1    value2
1       2       100       NAN
1       2       NAN       101
10      20      200       NAN    
10      20      NAN       202
10      2       345       345
```

And I want a dataframe like this:

```
id_1    id_2    value1    value2
1       2       100       101
10      20      200       202    
a       b       c         d
```

Basically, if both ID columns match up, then there will definitely be a `value-nan` vs `nan-value` situation, and I want to combine the rows by just replacing the `nans`.

Does pandas have a utility for this?  It's not quite stacking, or melting.  Maybe pivoting, but I'd need two indeces. And I want to preserve any rows that don't have both indeces matching.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single command for your purpose and many different ways to accomplish this. However, you can use `melt` and `pivot` after each other:

```
id_vars = ["id_1", "id_2"]
melted = df.melt(id_vars=id_vars).dropna()
pivoted = melted.pivot_table(index=id_vars, columns="variable", values="value")

print(pivoted)

    variable    value1  value2
id_1    id_2        
1       2       100.0   101.0
10      2       345.0   345.0
        20      200.0   202.0
```

But, the above solution is slower than two following solutions.

First, you can use forward fill `ffill` to fill NaNs and `last` to get the last row which contains all valid values due to `ffill`:

```
ids = ["id_1", "id_2"]

df.groupby(ids).ffill()\
  .groupby(ids).last()\
  .reset_index()

    id_1    id_2    value1  value2
0   1       2       100     101
1   10      2       345     345
2   10      20      200     202
```

Second, instead of grouping twice (since `ffill` returns a data frame), you may use a custom `apply` which has the same result:

```
def collapse(x):
    return x.ffill().iloc[-1, 2:]

df.groupby(ids).apply(collapse).reset_index()
```

Even though we use an apply here, it is the fastest solution (at least for your provided dummy data - it may scale differently for larger datasets).

Answer (score 0):

One way (df is your initial dataframe):

```
df1=df.dropna(subset=["value1"]).drop("value2",axis=1)
df2=df.dropna(subset=["value2"]).drop("value1",axis=1)
dfNew=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` + `first`

```
df=df.replace('NAN',np.nan) # make sure it is np.nan not string NAN

df.groupby(['id_1','id_2'],as_index=False).first()
Out[37]: 
   id_1  id_2 value1 value2
0     1     2    100    101
1    10     2    345    345
2    10    20    200    202
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sum it together as `np.nan` will be ignored by default.

```
df = df.replace("NAN", np.nan). # turn "NAN" to np.nan
df.groupby(["id_1", "id_2"])["value1", "value2"].sum().reset_index()
```