# Pandas DataFrame combine rows by column value, where rows can have NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
            timestamp       A       B       C       D       E       F
0           1607594400000   83.69   NaN     NaN     NaN     1003.20 8.66
1           1607594400000   NaN     2.57    44.35   17.18   NaN     NaN
2           1607595000000   83.07   NaN     NaN     NaN     1003.32 8.68
3           1607595000000   NaN     3.00    42.31   20.08   NaN     NaN
..          ...             ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
325         1607691600000   90.19   NaN     NaN     NaN     997.32  10.22
326         1607691600000   NaN     1.80    30.10   14.85   NaN     NaN
328         1607692200000   NaN     1.60    26.06   12.78   NaN     NaN
327         1607692200000   91.33   NaN     NaN     NaN     997.52  10.21
```

I need to combine the rows that have the same value for timestamp, where in the cases where there is `nan-value` the value is maintained and in the cases where there is `value-value` the average of the values is calculated.

I tried the solution of the following question but it is not exactly my situation and I don't know how to addapt it:
[pandas, combine rows based on certain column values and NAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115481/pandas-combine-rows-based-on-certain-column-values-and-nan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('timestamp', as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: you just love groupby :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it throws me the error ```pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```, it should be for trying to treat NaNs as values. If there is no other way to do it I will implement the version that @BENY proposes that maybe I could it.

Comment: You might have some group that have no values (all `NaN`) so `mean` fails.

Comment: True, it worked perfectly. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `first`, it will pick the not null value for each group

```
out = df.groupby('timestamp', as_index=False).first()
```

Or

```
out = df.set_index('timestamp').mean(level=0)
```

Comment: first wouldn't do *where there is value-value the average of the values is calculated*...